# javascript print tofixed and if not possible print normal

Tags: javascript, html, tofixed

So I have some values that should be printed as toFixed(8), but sometimes it happens that the value is a string with text and therefore everything that comes behind that (in a loop) is forgotten due to the error.

Is there any possibility to use toFixed(8) if it can and otherwise print the var without tofixed?

```js
$.each(trades, function(_, obj) {
  if (obj['sold'] == true) {
    if (obj['enddate'] === undefined) {
      count = 1
      profit = obj['profit_percentage']
      tradeList.add({
        startdate: obj['datetime'],
        if (typeof obj['buyprice'] === "number") {
          buyprice: obj['buyprice'].toFixed(8)
        }
        else {
          buyprice: obj['buyprice']
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what do you mean "is forgotten"? is there mixed data of numbers and strings in your loop?

Comment: are you seeing something like `"myString".toFixed is not a function` ?

Comment: yes there is mixed data, so I want to do toFixed if its possible and otherwise just use without toFixed.

this kind of errors happen in console if I try .toFixed on something that cant do it:
https://imgur.com/a/COhwMHN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to check if the current value is a number you can use toFixed on- as long as your numbers aren't also strings.

```js
var myMixedData = ["string", 0.3434, .434234434533422, "anotherString", .2434242];

myMixedData.forEach(function(thing) {
  if (typeof thing === "number") {
    console.log(thing.toFixed(8));
  } else {
    console.log(thing);
  }
});
```

After seeing your code here is a more detailed answer that may be of more help. I wasn't sure what type of obj `tradeList` is, but here it is an array of objects.

```js
var trades = [{"sold": true,"datetime": "date1","buyprice": 23.343252}, {"sold": true,"datetime": "date2","buyprice": "justAStringHere"}];

var tradeList = [];

$.each(trades, function(_, obj) {
  if (obj['sold'] == true) {
    if (obj['enddate'] === undefined) {
      count = 1;
      //profit  = obj['profit_percentage']
      var tradeListObj = {};
      tradeListObj.startDate = obj['datetime'];
      
      var buyprice = obj['buyprice'];
      if (typeof buyprice === "number") {
        buyprice = buyprice.toFixed(8);
      }
      
      tradeListObj.buyprice = buyprice;
      tradeList.push(tradeListObj);
    }
  }
});

console.log(tradeList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ah damn, why so easy :D

thank you for your answer, my browser shows the following error when doing this:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token typeof

Comment: what browser are you using? also it would help to post your code. Maybe there is a small syntax error too

Comment: @AndrewLohr Add an `else` clause to print `thing` normally.

Comment: `if (typeof obj['buyprice'] === "number") {
            buyprice: obj['buyprice'].toFixed(8),
          } else {
            buyprice: obj['buyprice'],
          }`

Comment: @p0nts can you edit your original post with this code, but also include the loop too? not sure what `else { buyprice: obj['buyprice'], }` is trying to do

Comment: @p0nts what type of object is `tradeList`? looks like you are mixing code in places it shouldn't be

Comment: @p0nts I added a more detailed answer for you

Comment: thank you very much, its something from listjs I was using to build lists for search :) https://www.listjs.com

Answer (score 0):

It always can, Number.prototype.toFixed returns a string representation of the result.

So, 0.123.toFixed(2) is actually a string '0.12'.
And if you want it to become a number, use unary plus: +0.123.toFixed(2) will return a number 0.12.

Other situation, if your input is not a number, but it is a different story.

Hope, that I answered your question

Comment: yeah so something the value is not a number, then this fails.

I'd like to use .toFixed and if it errors proceed without .toFixed

this kind of errors happen in console if I try .toFixed on something that cant do it:
https://imgur.com/a/COhwMHN

Comment: The question says "sometimes it happens that the value is a string with text". So he's already stated that it's a different story, how does this answer help?